# How can we Create a Dataframe in Databricks Environment?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, databricks

I looked at the documentation in the link below and it seems like this is how you create a dataframe, from a list, in Databricks.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
details = [(name,cluster) for name, cluster in zip(scaledData,predictions)]
details_df = spark.createDataFrame(details)
```

When I try to run the code above, I get this error.

```
AssertionError: dataType <py4j.java_gateway.JavaMember object at 0x7f4efe8dca58> should be an instance of <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DataType'>
```

If anyone here has tried this and gotten it to work, please drop some knowledge on me.

https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/dataframes-datasets/introduction-to-dataframes-python.html

Comment: do you get any error, log from the above code?

Comment: Whoops.  Forgot to mention that part.  I just added it to my original post.

Comment: What datatypes are the objects "scaledData" and "predictions"? The code runs with no errors if those objects are both lists.